# Route traffic for spesific IP and interface

Tags: routing, firewall

I have a server CentOS8 that need to be routed. Im new with this and i hope this discussion will help me through the problem. I have the following setup:

```
    Device A             Device B            Device C
      VPN       ---->      VPN     ---->   Normal System
 192.168.71.42          10.184.0.3          10.48.0.5
```

All i want is Device A can communicate with Device C through the tunnel, vice versa. I've been reading some discussion and article but seems not have a clear way since the Device B and Device C just have one interface (some of them have 2 gw for each side).

I used this on Device C:
`ip route add 10.184.0.3 dev eth0` and `ip route add 192.168.71.42 via 10.184.0.3 dev eth0` but this route makes me cannot ping Device B from Device C. I've been read and tried using NAT forwarding and still not got the point. I need help with suggestion for this setup.

Comment: What VPN type are you using? Most VPNs (route-based) _will_ create a second virtual interface. Pure IPsec VPNs (policy-based) need a different approach.

Comment: Hi @user1686 , Im using Strongswan for the VPN.